# Button clickable area increased with pseudo-element (::after) not working in Firefox but in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, button

I was working on a hybrid app project that had a circular tap button implementation in it. For this, I created a circle by adjusting `height` `width` and `border-radius` properties and put a button inside it. However, I noticed that the button was placed close to the top of the circular shape so I decided to expand its clickable area as per [this](http://front-back.com/expand-clickable-areas-for-a-better-touch-experience). I only adjusted the `bottom` property as that was what I was looking for. It worked perfectly on Chrome (Version 48.0.2564.103 (64-bit)) but not on Firefox (Version Firefox ESR 38.6.0). Upon inspecting the element (on both browsers) I could see the `::after` tag has the whole circular area covered, but it's not clickable near the bottom region of the circle on Firefox. Any ideas explaining the behaviour would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: By the way, I achieved the intended functionality using a slightly varied approach, but I was actually looking for why such behaviour exists in different browsers!

Comment: At least make an example to present your issue, either as a snippet or a JSFiddle

Comment: I made an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/98j7vo8k/1/ I've got the same problem with Firefox 48.0b6

Comment: I submit a bug for that in bugzilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1286191